# Brightcove exoplayer in SDK 4.6.1 is not getiing imported

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, brightcove, exoplayer

I have tried maven/ compiled it as per the documentation . But the exo player in the android SDK isn't getting imported. This I have to use since I want to stream a HLS video.

import com.brightcove.player.view.BrightcoveExoPlayerVideoView;
 
This isn't getting imported.

Comment: can you add your gradle config

Comment: instructions for properly setting up your app may be found here https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/android-player-samples/tree/master/brightcove-exoplayer

Comment: dependencies {
    compile 'com.brightcove.player:exoplayer:4.6.+'
}  compile files('../android-native-player-public-4.6.1/hls-api3/android-hls-api3-player-4.6.1.jar')
    compile files('../android-native-player-public-4.6.1/sdk/android-sdk-4.6.1.jar') @petey this is my gradle file. I did follow the steps in the github project too

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the BrightcoveExoPlayerVideoView from gradle, you need to add the Brightcove public maven repo to your repositories.  Something like this:

```
repositories {
  jcenter()

  maven {
    url 'http://repo.brightcove.com/releases'
  }
}
```

and then you need to add the dependency to your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  compile "com.brightcove.player:exoplayer:4.7.2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same here in Android Studio, even version 4.7.2 
My guess is Gradle version incompatibility.

But manually importing the jar library should do the trick for now:

Download the SDK from https://docs.brightcove.com/en/perform/mobile-sdks/brightcove-player-sdk-for-android/index.html

In Android Studio Click on `Project Structure`

Select the `Dependencies` tab

Click on the small `+` sign on the left to add

Select `Import Jar/.aar Package`

Browse to where you downloaded the above SDK and import it

Now it's imported and ready

Comment: Yeah in the end had to resort to this only